# How to call a Java class from other context

Tags: java, jboss

Following is the structure of my deployable's in Jboss EAP 6:

```
mytest.ear
|
|
|---- mytestjar.jar 
|
|---- mytestwar.war (extracted folder)
|       |---- META-INF
|       |---- WEB-INF
|       |       |---- classes
|       |       |---- lib
|       |       |---- web.xml
|
|---- META-INF
|
|---- lib (Third-party jars)
|       |---- xyz.jar
|       |---- abc.jar
```

I want to call a java class which is present in 'mytestjar.jar' from 'mytestwar.war', 
how can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to call a bean. If yes then you can use context to lookup the bean

Answer (score 1):

The MANIFEST.MF file in your war should have reference to the jar like "Class-Path: mytestjar.jar", this way the classes from the jar can be accessed.